# How to continuously communicate between Java and Python using TCP socket

Tags: java, python

What I'm trying to do: Send an image from Java client to Python server. Python server detects an object from the image and sends back detection box coordinates. The server must remain connected.

Question 1: What is the best way to receive the data?

When I receive an image in Python, I use `clientsocket.recv(1024)` with a while loop but `recv` is blocking and not breaking the loop. 
Receiving data at once like using `recv(400000)` or breaking when `len(data) != 1024` both works but I would like to know if there is any other way to break the loop or to receive data because you might get an image bigger than `4000000` or data size that is multiple of `1024`.

Java is sending an image when I click a button in a UI. If I use `settimeout` or setblocking`, Python server will not wait until I click the button to image to send it.

Question 2: How do I maintain connection until Client closes?

Once connected, I put receiving an image and sending coordinates in a while loop so I don't have to reconnect every time I send an image. But because sending coordinates is in a while loop, Java client won't receive the coordinates until the while loop breaks.

Python Server:

```
clientsocket, addr = s.accept()
    while True:
        f = open('image.jpg', 'wb')
                while True:
                    data = clientsocket.recv(1024)
                    f.write(data)
                    if not data:
                        break
        detectObject("image.jpg")
        clientsocket.send(detection coordinates)
```

Java Client:

```
try {
    Socket socket = new Socket((host,port));
    // when click a button, it sends an image 
    ...
    bufferedReader.readLine;
    } catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace;}
// and some other codes
```

Java maintains the connection as long as Python server is alive. Just trying to figure out how to fix python server code such that it maintains the connection while receiving images and send back coordinates any time the client sends images.

As of now, the best thing I can do is reconnect each time the Python server sends back coordinates. But I would like to avoid reconnecting every time I send an image for object detection.

Comment: There's way too much code missing here, at least on the Java side.  Show us a [mcve] please.

Comment: I've done a fair amount of socket programming in Python.  If you can state your question more clearly, I can probably help you.

Comment: If one of your problems that you don't know how to read just the right amount of bytes from the socket for the image because the sender doesn't close the connection?  That's a classic problem.

Comment: All I want to do is stop receiving data and move on if your not getting anymore data. But in my code, recv(1024) is blocking the execution of the rest the code because it keeps waiting to get more data.

Comment: See my answer.  There is no way to know to move on if you don't know how much data to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code won't work if you want to reuse the socket for another request (that is, the client isn't going to close the socket after this request), and you don't know how big what you've been sent is.  There's really no good way to know where the end of the data is.

The simplest solution is to send a length before you send the image.  Then you can read just the right amount of data off of the socket.  So your code might look like this:

```
clientsocket, addr = s.accept()
while True:
    data = clientsocket.recv(4)
    # ... turn 4 bytes in 'data' into integer 'count'
    f = open('image.jpg', 'wb')
    while count > 0:
        data = clientsocket.recv(min(count, 1024))
        count -= len(data)
        f.write(data)
    detectObject("image.jpg")
    clientsocket.send(detection coordinates)
```

If I understand your question right, this would solve both of your problems

Comment: Sending the size data before sending the actual image data works perfectly. Thank you so much for your help. 
Now, when I send back the coordinates, Java client is not reading the coordinates data until the while True loop in python server breaks... but I would like to receive the coordinates data while maintaining the connection. Do you have any solutions for that ?

Comment: Why would breaking out of the loop break the connection? - don't you want just what is in the code you gave?  You want to break out of the inner loop, send the response, and then take the next request via the outer loop?  That looks like it will work fine.  Your code is exactly the basic form that most small servers take.

Comment: actually, what you do want is to break out of the outer loop and close the socket connection if you get a EOF.  This means the client has closed their end of the connection, and you want to then clean up your side and then call listen() again.